# Php pdo_dblib sql server pagination

Tags: php, sql-server, pagination, declare

I can execute query like this against sql server:

```
DECLARE @ROWS INT = 2, @PAGE INT = 2
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS _NO
    FROM [Reports].[dbo].[Cycle] 
) AS SOD
WHERE SOD._NO BETWEEN ((@PAGE-1)*@ROWS)+1
AND @ROWS*(@PAGE)
GO
```

and i got result:

[image: result of executing query]

but if i try to do so in pdo through dblib it doesn't work:

```
            $stmt = $pdo->query("
    DECLARE @ROWS INT = 2, @PAGE INT = 2
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS _NO
        FROM [Reports].[dbo].[Cycle] 
    ) AS SOD
    WHERE SOD._NO BETWEEN ((@PAGE-1)*@ROWS)+1
    AND @ROWS*(@PAGE)
    GO
    ");

            var_dump($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

error code:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 102 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [102] (severity 15)
```

description of error according error mesages: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-1-500.aspx

is:

```
Incorrect syntax near '%.*ls'.
```

Comment: You are declaring variables, declaring a query and executing it. While SQL Server is able to parse these 3 commands sequentially, PDO is trying to send all 3 of them as a single sentece. Moreover, you're using a query operator. You could try separating these 3 sections with semicolons and using exec operator.

Comment: ->exec() changes nothing because it's only return numbers of rows instead of statemetn object, executing is in the same way like in query.


$stmt = $pdo->exec("
DECLARE \@ROWS INT = 2, \@PAGE INT = 2;
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS _NO
FROM [Reports].[dbo].[Cycle]
) AS SOD
WHERE SOD._NO BETWEEN ((\@PAGE-1)*\@ROWS)+1
AND \@ROWS*(\@PAGE);
GO
");
     print_r($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));


error:

    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 102 General SQL ...

Comment: You have a point. I still believe that query won't be able to parse 3 sequential commands. Did you try the semicolons?